# Combinar sistema de score con timer en unity3D para ser reciclado en jugabilidad

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity2d

Muy buen día.
Me encuentro desarrollando mí primer juego en unity v.2020.3.13f1 con c# en visual studio 2019.
Mí lógica todavía no es buena para desarrollar, la mecánica principal del juego por mí mismo y llevo con esto unas semanas sin poder resolverlo.
Esa mecánica es la combinación del puntaje obtenido en el score para ser usado después como un timer para avanzar,
es decir; al destruir todos los enemigos de la oleada A, se obtiene un total
de 60 puntos y en cuanto se llega a 60, el score comienza a decrementar
una unidad por segundo, hasta volver a llegar a 0. Una vez llegando a 0
se activa la oleada de enemigos A, para volver a llegar a 60 y así se repite
el proceso para reciclar la mecánica principal.
En pocas palabras, existen 2 eventos que funcionan a través de los valores máximo
del puntaje (60) ó en el valor mínimo (0).

Evento A: Cuando el valor del score es igual a 0, activa las siguientes intrucciones:
1.- Desactiva el renderizado de algunos objetos en la escena (esto se hace para agregar dificultad). Esta
primera intrucción se comunica con el script encargado de activar y desactivar el renderizado. Por ahora
lo activo manualmente con una tecla para hacer pruebas, pero quisiera activarlo correctamente con el evento
del score, porque tenerlo en el update me ha traído problemas de rendimiento (son muchos objetos). Los objetos,
deben mantener desactivado su renderizado, hasta que no se alcancen los 60 puntos.
2.- Se activa la oleada de enemigos tipo "A" (los que otorgan puntos al score al destruirlos). Cada
enemigo otorga 5 puntos al score, para poder llegar a 60 al matar a los 12 enemigos de la oleada.
3.- El score debe sumar puntos normalmente al matar enemigos, pero no debe comenzar a disminuir, antes
de llegar a los 60 puntos. Este es uno de mis problemas constantes, porque con algunas pruebas,
el score comienza a decrementar desde que se obtienen los primeros 5 puntos ó al llegar a 60
comienza a disminuír y se detiene totalmente, quedándose en 59.87566.

Evento B: Cuando el valor del score es igual a 60, activa las siguientes intrucciones:
1.- Debe activar el timer que reste una unidad por segundo, hasta llegar a 0 y así reiniciar jugabilidad.
2.- Activa el renderizado de los objetos que se encuentran desactivados, (hasta que no se alcancen los 60 puntos)
y deben mantener activado el renderizado, mientras aún queden segundos disponibles en el timer (hasta que llegue a 0 nuevamente).
Así, cuando se llega a 0, vuelven a desactivarse y se recicla la desaparición y aparición de objetos, que suman dificultad.
3.- Se activa la oleada de enemigos tipo "B" (estos no otorgan puntos para evitar sumar al score y sólo se
usan para agregar dificultad en el avance que tiene el jugador en los 60 segundos que obtiene después de eliminar
la oleada de enemigos tipo A).

Hice funcionar esto con un búcle que se activa cuando sólo una condición es verdadera, pero
tener búcles en un update... me ha causado problemas de rendimiento y crasheos, por lo mismo,
quiero evitar en lo posible los errores de novato al depender totalmente del método update y peor...
con bucles dentros de él.
Por eso pido un poco de asesoría, para abordar mejor la solución de problema.

Muchas gracias por su atención y excelentes días en su vida.

Les adjunto el script que regrese a su forma básica, después de crashear el programa con tantos búcles
y cosas raras que tenía, pero de la manera que está referenciado, se entiende mejor la explicación descríta anteriormente, creo.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PointTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
/*Estas variables quedaron sobrando de unas pruebas que hice, 
 * pero no sé si serán necesarias.*/
public float maxValue = 60;

public float minValue = 0;

/*También probé, dándole un rango de "0 a 60", para no exceder y estar dentro del parámetro de uso que quiero, pero tampoco funcionó
  *Dejé la variable en puntos, porque me basé en un sistema habitual para implementar un score al destruir enemigos */
[SerializeField] private float _points;

// La referencia a mí componente Text de la UI
[SerializeField] private Text _pointsText;


private void Start()
{        
    if (_pointsText != null) //Me aseguro de tener una componente de texto asociada, para evitar otro kabom que ya tuve en el juego.
        _pointsText.text = _points.ToString(); // Actualiza los puntos otorgados en el HUD del canvas
}

public void UpdateScore(float amount) //Se comunica con el script "EnemyUI", que también anexaré abajo de este.
{
    _points += amount; //Añade o resta (en caso de tener valores negativos)
    if (_pointsText != null) //Me aseguro de tener una componente de texto asociada, para evitar otro kabom que ya tuve en el juego.
        _pointsText.text = _points.ToString(); // Actualiza los puntos en el HUD
          
}

public void Update()
{
    /*Ejecuta el método que quiero implementar para decrementar el valor del score, pero no pude unir todos los eventos
    * que deben ocurrir en ese mismo método y por eso los tengo separados abajo casi como pseudo código*/
    TimerEvent();
}

public void TimerEvent() //Aquí estaba probando un timer básico con el valor que se actualiza por código en el componente Text
{
    //Lo dejé así, porque rompí unity con bucles y ya no le moví más, pero sirve para explicar la idea principal.
    if (_points == 60)//Cuando el score es 60, debe activar estos métodos, que sólo estarán activos los 60 segundos que dura el timer.

    {
        _points -= Time.deltaTime; // Esta es mí implementación básica del timer que resta una unidad por segundo
        _pointsText.text = _points.ToString("f0"); // Actualiza los puntos en el HUD

        Hiding hidingEvent = FindObjectOfType<Hiding>(); //Busca los objetos que contengan el componente Hiding
        EnemyPool enemyPool = FindObjectOfType<EnemyPool>(); //Busca los objetos que contengan el componente EnemyPool

        //Ejecutar la función que activa el render de las puertas
        hidingEvent.EnableChildComponents(); // Se comunica con el script "Hiding" que sólo habilita o el componente Renderer
        //Ejecutar el spawn de los 15 enemigos tipo A
        enemyPool.ActivateEnemyA(); // Se comunica con el spawner de enemigos


    }
    else
    {
        if (_points == 0)//Cuando el score es 0, debe activar estos métodos, que sólo estarán activos hasta conseguir 30 segundos en el score, otra vez.
        {
                           
                Hiding hidingEvent = FindObjectOfType<Hiding>(); //Busca los objetos que contengan el componente Hiding
                EnemyPoolB enemyPoolB = FindObjectOfType<EnemyPoolB>(); //Busca los objetos que contengan el componente EnemyPoolB

                //Ejecutar la función que desactiva los muros
                hidingEvent.DisableChildComponents(); // Se comunica con el script "Hiding" que sólo deshabilita el componente Renderer
                                                      //Ejecutar el spawn de los 15 enemigos tipo B
                enemyPoolB.ActivateEnemyB(); //Se comunica con el spawner de enemigos

            
        }
    }
}



}
```

Este es el código que desactiva y activa el render de los objetos:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Hiding : MonoBehaviour
{
 public Renderer rend;

private void Start()
{
   rend = GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>();
}

/*private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J))
    {
        EnableChildComponents();
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.H))
    {
        DisableChildComponents();
    }
}*/

public void EnableChildComponents()
{
    rend.enabled = true;
}

public void DisableChildComponents()
{
   rend.enabled = false;
}
}
```

y este es el código genérico que ocupo en el pool de enemigos, la única diferencia es que uno es para los enemigos tipo a ó b

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyPool : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform enemyStart;
public List<GameObject> enemyList;

public void Update()
{
    ActivateEnemyA();
}

public void ActivateEnemyA()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.N))
    {
        GameObject enemy = GetEnemy();
        PrepareEnemy(enemy);
    }
}

private GameObject GetEnemy()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < enemyList.Count; i++) //Recorre la lista de enemigos
    {
        if(enemyList[i].activeInHierarchy == false) //Si el enemigo contenido en "i", está inactiva
        {
            return enemyList[i];// Devuelve el enemigo de la posición "i"
        }
    }
    return null; //En caso de recorrer toda la lista sin encontrar enemigos, devuelve un null
}

private void PrepareEnemy(GameObject enemy)
{
    if(enemy != null)
    {
        enemy.transform.position = enemyStart.position;
        enemy.SetActive(true);
        
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que mires este [Tutorial de Academia de Videojuegos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5LYuA2d_Zg) sobre Corrutinas que es lo que e usado para resolver tu problema y puedas usarlo en el futuro son muy útiles!

Creo que conseguí lo que buscabas pero no estoy seguro!

Reemplaza el código del Script PointTimer con este:

```
public float maxValue = 60;

public float minValue = 0;

/*También probé, dándole un rango de "0 a 60", para no exceder y estar dentro del parámetro de uso que quiero, pero tampoco funcionó
  *Dejé la variable en puntos, porque me basé en un sistema habitual para implementar un score al destruir enemigos */
[SerializeField] private float _points;

// La referencia a mí componente Text de la UI
[SerializeField] private Text _pointsText;

// -- Se guardan las referencias a cada elemento que se necesite utilizar mas de una vez --

Hiding hidingEvent = null; // Referencia a Hiding
EnemyPool enemyPool = null; //Referencia a EnemyPool

bool isOverMaxPoint = false;
bool isTimerActive = false;

private void Awake()
{
    // -- Se buscan las referencias al comenzar el juego --
    hidingEvent = FindObjectOfType<Hiding>(); //Busca los objetos que contengan el componente Hiding
    enemyPool = FindObjectOfType<EnemyPool>(); //Busca los objetos que contengan el componente EnemyPool

}

private void Start()
{
    if (_pointsText != null) //Me aseguro de tener una componente de texto asociada, para evitar otro kabom que ya tuve en el juego.
        _pointsText.text = _points.ToString(); // Actualiza los puntos otorgados en el HUD del canvas


    //Dejamos en control a las corrutinas para conseguir el comportamiento deseado
    TimerEvent();
}

private void Update()
{
    isOverMaxPoint = _points >= maxValue;

    if (isOverMaxPoint && !isTimerActive)
    {
        TimerEvent();
    }
}


// Se llama una vez en el Start, Awake o Enable
public void TimerEvent() //Aquí estaba probando un timer básico con el valor que se actualiza por código en el componente Text
{

    StartCoroutine(EventA());
}


IEnumerator EventA()
{
    isTimerActive = true; // timer activado

    Debug.Log("Enemigos Tipo A");

    hidingEvent.DisableChildComponents(); // Se comunica con el script "Hiding" que sólo deshabilita el componente Renderer
    //Ejecutar el spawn de los 15 enemigos tipo A
    enemyPool.ActivateEnemyA(); // Se comunica con el spawner de enemigos


    // Al salir de ciclo cambiamos de evento

    // Esperamos que cuando nuestros puntos alcancen el valor maximo

    yield return new WaitUntil(() => _points >= maxValue);
    StartCoroutine(EventB());
}

IEnumerator EventB()
{
    Debug.Log("Enemigos Tipo B");

    //Ejecutar la función que desactiva los muros
    enemyPoolB.ActivateEnemyB(); //Se comunica con el spawner de enemigos

    //Ejecutar el spawn de los 15 enemigos tipo B
    hidingEvent.EnableChildComponents(); // Se comunica con el script "Hiding" que sólo habilita o el componente Renderer

    while (_points > minValue)
    {
        UpdatePointsInternal(-Time.deltaTime);
        UpdatePointText();

        yield return null;
    }

    isTimerActive = false; // timer desactivado

    // Al salir de ciclo cambiamos de evento

    // Nos pasamos al Evento A
    StartCoroutine(EventA());

}


private void UpdatePointText()
{
    if (!_pointsText) return; // es lo mismo que _pointsText != null
    _pointsText.text = _points.ToString();
}

public void UpdateScore(float amount) //Se comunica con el script "EnemyUI", que también anexaré abajo de este.
{
    //_points += amount; //Añade o resta (en caso de tener valores negativos)
    //_points = Mathf.Clamp(_points, minValue, maxValue); // nos aseguramos que no se pase de rango

    // lo mismo de arriba solo que un poco mas elegante!
    UpdatePointsInternal(amount);

    //if (_pointsText != null) //Me aseguro de tener una componente de texto asociada, para evitar otro kabom que ya tuve en el juego.
    //_pointsText.text = _points.ToString(); // Actualiza los puntos en el HUD
   
    // Lo mismo de arriba solo que un poco mas elegante!
    UpdatePointText();
}


private void UpdatePointsInternal(float amount)
{
    _points += amount;
    // Se usa el Clamp para evitar anomalias como (1.0f == 1.01f = false)
    _points = Mathf.Clamp(_points, minValue, maxValue);
}
```

Comment: Ya he cambiado el código anterior por tu sugerencia, pero no ejecuta los eventos.
Me encuentro analizando el código a profundidad para encontrar el motivo y en cuanto encuentre el motivo te lo compartiré por aquí. También le daré un espacio a los cursos que me comentaste para ver si eso me ayuda a solucionar este problema. 
Gracias y buen día @Nomar

Comment: Saludos!, Bueno una cosas que no me quedo muy clara es si hay necesidad de estar llamando a estas funciones `hidingEvent.DisableChildComponents();` y `enemyPoolB.ActivateEnemyB();` a cada frame, que es lo que hacen?, desactivan múltiples elementos o activan múltiples enemigos respectivamente dependiendo de algo o que? no lo se, pero si hay necesidad de llamar a esas funciones a cada frame hay puede estar el error.

Comment: O también puede ser que me haya confundido en la lógica por que hice que el **EventoA** se ejecutara al inicio para que espere con esta linea `yield return new WaitUntil(() => _points >= maxValue);`  hasta que la cantidad de puntos sea mayor o igual valor **maxValue** luego de ser true pasar a ejecutar el **EventoB** que reduce los puntos hasta llegar a 0 y vuelve al **EventoA** donde se espera a que los puntos (que mas bien me parece tiempo) sean mayor a 60 nuevamente

Comment: Según mí lógica básica, sólo el timer debe ejecutarse cada frame. Las oleadas de enemigos y la desactivación y activación del componente renderer, no se ejecutan cada frame (pero como mencioné, es visto desde mí lógica básica de programación), quizá sí se requiera una llama por frame, aunque lo dudo y explicaré por qué. Verás cuando los activaba o desactivaba mediante un tecla, no requería mantenerla pulsada para que se mantuviera el efecto, es decir; si desactivaba el render, se quedaba así hasta que volviera a presionar la tecla y viceversa. Pensé que podía ser un error entre scripts.

Comment: Estoy revisando eso, para ver si no se ejecutan los códigos por algún cambio que haya hecho en el pool o el controlador del renderer, pero... Si dejo de comentar las lineas que administran esa instrucción mediante el if(Input.GetKeyDown(keycode.h)) funciona bien, pero esa no es la solución porque pues... Eso me trae problemas de optimización por tenerlo en el update. Te anexo el código para ocultar y el pool genérico de los enemigos, para que veas si ahí quizá está el error de compatibilidad

Comment: Ay... no me deja poner el código aquí. Disculpa. 
Lo anexaré en el hilo principal de la pregunta (como respuesta propia), porque cuando formulaba la pregunta principal, el código me hacía cosas raras en el formato que usa el portal. y sólo dejé el código del PointTimer, que era el que consideraba más preocupante.

Comment: Ojalá que con los códigos complementarios que se comunican con el pointTimer, encontremos la solución. He estado revisando esto en unity, pero el contador sólo llega a 60 y no activa o desativa los eventos, pensé que era debido al número de enemigos que tenía ó al tiempo que otorgaban al destruírlos, pero aunque he cambiado esos valores... sigue sin funcionar. En teoría cuando inicia el juego (estando en 0) deberían de desaparecer objetos, pero desde ahí supe que no funcionaba. Te agradezco la ayuda y por eso estoy revisando tu código, para hacerlo funcionar.

Comment: Resumo la función que busco obtener:
Caso 1:
(inicio de juego y después del primer ciclo de la mecánica
Cuando _Points = 0; entonces se desactiva el render de los objetos y se mantienen desativados hasta llegar a 60, también se activa el spawn de enemigos, pero sólo cuando el valor es 0 (no necesito que se ejecute esta tarea cada frame), porque en teoría se spawnean 15 enemigos al mismo tiempo y eso da los puntos necesarios para llegar a 60.

Comment: Caso2: (Cuando se alcanza 60 puntos en el score)
Cuando _points = 60, entonces se activa el render de los objetos y se mantienen activador hasta que el contador se vacié totalmente y llegue a 0, se activa el otro spawn de los enemigos, pero sólo cuando el valor es igual a 60, aplica la misma lógica que en el de arriba, porque funciona igual y obviamente en cuanto llega a 60, también se activa la cuenta atrás, par vaciar el score una unidad por segundo y volver a llegar a 0. Esto asegura reciclar la mecánica de activar y desactivar el render y enemigos, según el valor del score.

Comment: ok, creo que e encontrado el problema!

Comment: dame un momento y te explico

Comment: Cierto. Dentro del primer código que sugeriste, hacía falta una referencia al pool de los enemigos tipo b y como no estaba cacheada con la otras búsquedas de componentes, marcaba error. Lo comento, por si eso se te pasó por accidente o fue a propósito debido a lo que tenías a la mano en ese momento.

Comment: Jerarquía:
    + objeto padre vacío "llamado obstáculo invisible"
      -Hijo1- Pared
      -Hijo2 -Pared
      -Hijo3 -Pared

Comment: Ya no sé qué más aportar para la solución de esto. :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok Carlos, creo que esta es la definitiva xD.

Los detalles están comentados en el código cualquier duda le estaré dando vueltas a esto!

```
        public class Points : MonoBehaviour
    {
    
    
        public float maxValue = 60;
    
        public float minValue = 0;
    
        /*También probé, dándole un rango de "0 a 60", para no exceder y estar dentro del parámetro de uso que quiero, pero tampoco funcionó
          *Dejé la variable en puntos, porque me basé en un sistema habitual para implementar un score al destruir enemigos */
        [SerializeField] private float _points;
    
        // La referencia a mí componente Text de la UI
        [SerializeField] private Text _pointsText;
    
        // -- Se guardan las referencias a cada elemento que se necesite utilizar mas de una vez --
    
        Hiding hidingEvent = null; //Busca los objetos que contengan el componente Hiding
        EnemyPool enemyPool = null; //Busca los objetos que contengan el componente EnemyPool
    
    
        private void Awake()
        {
            // -- Se buscan las referencias al comenzar el juego --
            hidingEvent = FindObjectOfType<Hiding>(); //Busca los objetos que contengan el componente Hiding
            enemyPool = FindObjectOfType<EnemyPool>(); //Busca los objetos que contengan el componente EnemyPool
    
        }
    
        private void Start()
        {
            if (_pointsText != null) //Me aseguro de tener una componente de texto asociada, para evitar otro kabom que ya tuve en el juego.
                _pointsText.text = _points.ToString(); // Actualiza los puntos otorgados en el HUD del canvas
    
    
            //Dejamos en control a las corrutinas para conseguir el comportamiento deseado
            TimerEvent();
        }
    
        // Se llama una vez en el Start, Awake o Enable
        public void TimerEvent() //Aquí estaba probando un timer básico con el valor que se actualiza por código en el componente Text
        {
    
            StartCoroutine(EventA());
        }
    
    
        IEnumerator EventA()
        {
       
    
            Debug.Log("Enemigos Tipo A");
    
      
    
      
            hidingEvent.DisableChildComponents(); // Se comunica con el script "Hiding" que sólo deshabilita el componente Renderer
    
            enemyPool.ActivateDisableEnemys(); // Se comunica con el spawner de enemigos
    
    
            //Ejecutar el spawn de los 15 enemigos tipo A
    
    
            // Al salir de ciclo cambiamos de evento
    
            // Esperamos que cuando nuestros puntos alcancen el valor maximo
    
            yield return new WaitUntil(() => _points >= maxValue);
            StartCoroutine(EventB());
        }
    
        IEnumerator EventB()
        {
            Debug.Log("Enemigos Tipo B");
    
            //Ejecutar el spawn de los 15 enemigos tipo B
            //enemyPoolB.ActivateEnemyB(); //Se comunica con el spawner de enemigos
    
            //Ejecutar la función que desactiva los muros
            hidingEvent.EnableChildComponents(); // Se comunica con el script "Hiding" que sólo habilita o el componente Renderer
    
            while (_points > minValue)
            {
                UpdatePointsInternal(-Time.deltaTime * 3);
                UpdatePointText();
    
                yield return null;
            }
    
            //isTimerActive = false; // timer desactivado
    
            // Al salir de ciclo cambiamos de evento
    
            // Nos pasamos al Evento A
            StartCoroutine(EventA());
    
        }
    
    
        private void UpdatePointText()
        {
            if (!_pointsText) return; // es lo mismo que _pointsText != null
            _pointsText.text = _points.ToString();
        }
    
        public void UpdateScore(float amount) //Se comunica con el script "EnemyUI", que también anexaré abajo de este.
        {
            //_points += amount; //Añade o resta (en caso de tener valores negativos)
            //_points = Mathf.Clamp(_points, minValue, maxValue); // nos aseguramos que no se pase de rango
    
            // lo mismo de arriba solo que un poco mas elegante!
            UpdatePointsInternal(amount);
    
            //if (_pointsText != null) //Me aseguro de tener una componente de texto asociada, para evitar otro kabom que ya tuve en el juego.
            //_pointsText.text = _points.ToString(); // Actualiza los puntos en el HUD
    
            // Lo mismo de arriba solo que un poco mas elegante!
            UpdatePointText();
        }
    
    
        private void UpdatePointsInternal(float amount)
        {
            _points += amount;
            // Se usa el Clamp para evitar anomalias como (1.0f > 1.01f = false)
            _points = Mathf.Clamp(_points, minValue, maxValue);
        }
    
    }
```

Componente EnemyPool

```
        public class EnemyPool : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform enemyStart;
        public List<GameObject> enemyList;
    
    
        // La funcion ActivateEnemyA se estaba llamando constantemente por lo que si eliminabas un enemigo de tipo A
        // Reapareceria al instante, creo que no es el resultado buscado por lo que lo comente!
    
        //private void Update()
        //{
        //    ActivateEnemyA();
        //}
    
    
    
        // Un pequeño detalle aqui y es que de la lista de enemigos solo sacas 1, por cada llamada, entonces
        // lo ideal seria activar aquellos enemigos que no lo esten por lo que ActivateEnemyA() no nos esta ayudando mucho
        public void ActivateEnemyA()
        {
            Debug.Log("Activating Enemy");
            GameObject enemy = GetEnemy();
            PrepareEnemy(enemy);
    
        }
    
        // El nombre es obvio pero por claridad lo que hace es: Activar los enemigos que no se encuentren activados en la lista
        public void ActivateDisableEnemys()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < enemyList.Count; i++) //Recorre la lista de enemigos
            {
                // !enemyList[i].activeInHierarchy es lo mismo que enemyList[i].activeInHierarchy == false
                if (!enemyList[i].activeInHierarchy)
                {
                    GameObject Enemy = enemyList[i];
                    PrepareEnemy(Enemy);
                }
            }
        }
    
    
        
    
        private GameObject GetEnemy()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < enemyList.Count; i++) //Recorre la lista de enemigos
            {
                if (enemyList[i].activeInHierarchy == false) //Si el enemigo contenido en "i", está inactiva
                {
                    return enemyList[i];// Devuelve el enemigo de la posición "i"
                }
            }
            return null; //En caso de recorrer toda la lista sin encontrar enemigos, devuelve un null
        }
    
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Activa un enemigo en el caso de no ser nulo y reestrablece su posicion al SpawnPoint
        /// <br/>
        /// <seealso cref="enemyStart"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="enemy"></param>
        private void PrepareEnemy(GameObject enemy)
        {
            if (enemy != null && enemyStart != null)
            {
                enemy.transform.position = enemyStart.position;
                enemy.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
                Debug.LogError($"Enemy Null o SpawnPoint no asignado en {name}");
        }
    
    
    }
```

Componente hiding:

```
    public class Hiding : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject RendereContainer;
    private Renderer[] Renderers;

    private void Start()
    {
        // No esta muy claro que es lo que buscas aqui!
        // Quieres esconder el objeto o solamente hacerlo no visible pero contar con las colisiones que puedan tener?
        // Tal pararece ser el caso que solo lo quieres esconder pero conservar las colisiones, si es lo contrario entonces hay que usar GetComponentsInChildren<T>();
        // Que a diferencia de el que usas este busca todos los Renderers de todos los objetos que sean hijos directo y el propio render del mismo componente Hiding

        Renderers = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();


        // Si solo quieres desactivar multiples objetos en el escenario puede usar un truco simple que consiste en:
        // Todos los objetos que se desactivaran seran nietos de un objeto que tenga este (Hiding) componente y lo desactivas asi
        // los demas hijos se desactivaran igualmente
        // Ejemplo: 
        // Hiding (GameObjet) // le dices a este que desactive a RenderContainer y el desactivara a sus hijos con RenderContainer.SetActive(false); y unity hara lo demas por ti!
        //         RenderContainer (GameObject)
        //                  Render1 (GameObject)
        //                  Render2 (GameObject)
        //                  Render3 (GameObject)
        //                  Render4 (GameObject)
    }

    /*private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J))
        {
            EnableChildComponents();
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.H))
        {
            DisableChildComponents();
        }
    }*/

    public void EnableRenderContainer(bool OnOff)
    {
        RendereContainer.SetActive(OnOff);
    }

    public void EnableChildComponents()
    {
        SetView(true);
    }

    public void DisableChildComponents()
    {
        SetView(false);
    }

    public void SetView(bool view)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Renderers.Length; i++)
        {
            Renderers[i].enabled = view;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Disculpa por responder un día después, pero la vacuna del covid me afectó demasiado. EL CÓDIGO para ocultar cosas funcionaba bien, desde la primera versión que te mandé. En estos momentos, me pondré a comprobar tus sugerencias, quizá esté mejor optimizada tu versión. Avisaré en unos momentos qué resultados tuvieron. Gracias por tu atención y tiempo.

Comment: Ya los estuve probando y no funcionó. Mmmh... Analizo y analizo la lógica que propones y no encuentro el error en el código. Hice cambios en la jerarquía y tampoco. De hecho, por tus comentarios, creo que debo describirte la jerarquía de los objetos que desaparecen y es la siguiente: El padre es un objeto vacío y sus hijos son unas paredes que estorban el paso al ser invisibles. De hecho, como decías, estos objetos, deben conservar su collider, aún con el render desactivado. Mmmh... Ya no sé qué aportar para solucionar esto y agradezco mucho tu ayuda, seguiré probando con tu sugerencia.

Comment: Analizo tu código y no entiendo por qué multiplicas el parámetro -Time.deltatime * 3 en tu método UpdatePointsInternal, es lo único que no entiendo de tu lógica en el script

Comment: Ya intentaste subir los puntos manualmente desde el inspector?, como no se en que lugar se aumentaban los puntos yo los aumentaba manualmente desde su propiedad en el inspector

Comment: Vale. Te contacto por discord. Sirve que con imágenes, todo se entenderá mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Les dejo la respuesta (divida por partes) que el usuario @Nomar ayudó a encontrar, con la intención de apoyar a las personas que quieran hacer
algo parecido a lo propuesto en la pregunta. Adjuntaré 5 scripts con su descripción correspondiente y su implementación
en el proyecto de unity.
Para empezar, las intrucciones de la mecánica de juego propuesta en la pregunta, se controla desde un script principal, llamado "Points",
ése mismo script se comunica con 4 scripts; El primero, encargado de la activación y desactivación del componente renderer de los objetos,
llamado "Hiding", el segundo, con el script encargado del pool de enemigos, llamado "EnemyPool", el tercero se comunica con
el script encargado de desactivar el enemigo al recibir el daño establecido por nuestro game desing, llamado "LifeEnemy"
y el cuarto se comunica con el script encargado de comunicarse con la UI encargada de registrar los puntos en el score al desactivar enemigos,
llamado "EnemyUI" (como nota adicional, los scripts 3 y 4, se pueden juntar en un solo script, dependerá del estilo de trabajo de cada desarrollador).

Parte 1 (script principal)

Script principal (Points): Encargado de la mecánica principal para controlar eventos que combinan un score y un timer que decrementa su valor una unidad por segundo,
incluso puede ser migrado a su Game Manager, para mantener un órden y no tener código espaguéti.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Points : MonoBehaviour
{

// Variable encargada de preestablecer el valor máximo del score para activar el evento del tipo B
public float maxValue = 60;
// Variable encargada de preestablecer el valor mínimo del score para activar el evento del tipo A
public float minValue = 0;


/* Dejé la variable en puntos, porque me basé en un sistema habitual para implementar un score al destruir enemigos
 pero es fácil de intuír que la variable puede ser llamada de "segundos", dependerá su comodidad para entender su implementación*/
[SerializeField] private float _points;

// La referencia a la componente Text de la UI dentro de su proyecto en unity.
[SerializeField] private Text _pointsText;

// Se guardan las referencias a cada elemento, que se necesiten utilizar más de una vez.

Hiding hidingEvent = null; // Busca los objetos que contengan el componente Hiding y mantiene su valor en nulo antes de ser usadas.
EnemyPool enemyPool = null; // Busca los objetos que contengan el componente EnemyPool y mantiene su valor en nulo antes de ser usadas.

/*Este es el diccionario usado para la implementación del pool de enemigos, se manejó como un diccionario,
 * porque los enemigos se encuentran preinstanciado en la jerarquía del proyecto, para ser desactivados y activados
 * en los momentos que se requieren. Lo práctico de esto, es que se pueden asignar en el inspector
 * enemigos diferentes y eso facilita las cosas para mantener variaciones de enemigos y no tener un estilo monótono*/
private Dictionary<TypePool, EnemyPool> EnemyPools = new Dictionary<TypePool, EnemyPool>();

private void Awake()
{
    /* Cacheo de referencias para mejorar la optimización de código.
     * Recuerden que se debe tener un control de objetos en su jerarquía cuando se realicen
     * búsquedas de componentes, es decir; Si el enemy pool requiere buscar al objeto de su
     * de su proyecto que contenga el componente hiding y se encuentra varios niveles arriba
     * esto les causará problemas de rendimiento si hacen su proyecto más grande
     * por eso mantengan una jerarquía organizada para reducir este cuello de botella
     * y jamás pongan esto en el update, por eso cacheén sus búsquedas. */
    
    hidingEvent = FindObjectOfType<Hiding>(); //Busca los objetos que contengan el componente Hiding
    enemyPool = FindObjectOfType<EnemyPool>(); //Busca los objetos que contengan el componente EnemyPool

    // Se comunica con el método para recorrer la lista del pool.
    GetAllPools();
}


private void Start()
{
    if (_pointsText != null) //Me aseguro de tener una componente de texto asociada, para evitar un kabom que ya tuve en el juego.
        _pointsText.text = _points.ToString(); // Actualiza los puntos otorgados en el HUD del canvas.


    // Dejamos en control a las corrutinas para conseguir el comportamiento deseado.
    TimerEvent();
}

// Se llama una vez en el Start, Awake o Enable
public void TimerEvent() //Inicia la comunicación de los eventos relacionados con los valores del tiempo (mínimo y máximo del score).
{
    // Inicia la corrutina del evento A
    StartCoroutine(EventA());
}

/* Lógica del evento del tipo A:
 * 1.- Se activa el pool de los enemigos tipo A (que otorgan puntos).
 * 2.- Se desactiva el componente renderer de los objetos
 * 3.- Se mantiene activa la función de asignación de puntos tras derrotar enemigos */
IEnumerator EventA()
{

    // Comunica en consola que se inicia la activación de enemigos tipo A
    Debug.Log("Enemigos Tipo A");


    hidingEvent.DisableChildComponents(); // Se comunica con el script "Hiding" que sólo deshabilita el componente Renderer

    EnemyPools[TypePool.EnemyA].ActivateDisableEnemys(); //Se comunica con el spawner de enemigos


    /* Ejecutar el spawn de los 15 enemigos tipo A
     * Al salir de ciclo cambiamos de evento
     * Esperamos que nuestros puntos alcancen el valor maximo
     * mediante la comunicación de asignación de puntaje "scripts de enemigos"
     * la corrutina espera que la declaración ternaria sea válida
     * para iniciar con el evento tipo B */

    yield return new WaitUntil(() => _points >= maxValue);
    StartCoroutine(EventB());
}

/* Lógica del evento del tipo B:
 * 1.- Se activa el pool de los enemigos tipo B (que no otorgan puntos).
 * 2.- Se activa el componente renderer de los objetos
 * 3.- Se activa el timer que decrementa su valor una unidad por segundo (aquí no se suman puntos) */
IEnumerator EventB()
{
    Debug.Log("Enemigos Tipo B");

    // 2 es el ID del pool de los enemigos tipo B

    EnemyPools[TypePool.EnemyB].ActivateDisableEnemys(); //Se comunica con el spawner de enemigos

    //Ejecutar la función que desactiva los muros
    hidingEvent.EnableChildComponents(); // Se comunica con el script "Hiding" que sólo habilita el componente Renderer

    while (_points > minValue)
    {
        UpdatePointsInternal(-Time.deltaTime);
        UpdatePointText();

        yield return null;
    }

    //isTimerActive = false; // timer desactivado

    // Al salir de ciclo cambiamos de evento

    // Nos pasamos al Evento A
    StartCoroutine(EventA());

}


private void UpdatePointText()
{
    if (!_pointsText) return; // es lo mismo que _pointsText != null
    _pointsText.text = _points.ToString();
}

public void UpdateScore(float amount) //Se comunica con el script "EnemyUI", que también se anexará
{
    //_points += amount; //Añade o resta (en caso de tener valores negativos)
    //_points = Mathf.Clamp(_points, minValue, maxValue); // nos aseguramos que no se pase de rango

    // Lo mismo de arriba sólo que un poco más elegante, pero se mantienen los arreglos anteriores por si son necesarios.
    UpdatePointsInternal(amount);

    //if (_pointsText != null) //Me aseguro de tener una componente de texto asociada, para evitar otro kabom que ya tuve en el juego.
    //_pointsText.text = _points.ToString(); // Actualiza los puntos en el HUD

    // Lo mismo de arriba sólo que un poco más elegante, pero se mantienen los arreglos anteriores por si son necesarios.
    UpdatePointText();
}

private void GetAllPools()
{
    // Todas las pool de enemigos en el Sceneraio (sirve para mantener tipos diferentes de enemigos).
    EnemyPool[] AllEnemyPools = FindObjectsOfType<EnemyPool>();

    /* Búcle que recorre la lista y se asegura de tener enemigos disponibles
     * en necesario aclarar, que no es un pool dinámica y por lo mismo no permite
     * crecer. Esta pool sólo aplica para enemigos preinstanciados, es decir;
     * un número controlado de GameObjects preparados manualmente en la escena. */
    for (int i = 0; i < AllEnemyPools.Length; i++)
    {
        EnemyPool currentPool = AllEnemyPools[i];


        /* Nos fijamos si existe un id igual al que queremos insertar, de existir esta condicion será "false", por el uso del
         * operador de negacion booleana  ( ! ) EnemyPools.ContainsKey(currentPool.PoolID). */ 
        if (!EnemyPools.ContainsKey(currentPool.PoolType))
        {
            // Añadimos el ID al igual que su correspondiente Pool De Enemigos
            EnemyPools.Add(currentPool.PoolType, currentPool);
        }
        else
        {
            //Instrucción de comprobación correcta de la aplicación del pool.
            Debug.LogWarning($"Ya existe un Enemy pool con ID: {enemyPool.PoolType}");
        }
    }
}

/* Método que se comunica con la asignación de puntaje, mediante la eliminación de enemigos,
 * se comunica con el script "EnemyUI" */
private void UpdatePointsInternal(float amount)
{
    _points += amount;
    // Se usa el Clamp para evitar anomalias como (1.0f > 1.01f = false)
    _points = Mathf.Clamp(_points, minValue, maxValue);
}

}

/* Un enumerado que se encarga de administrar el ID de los enemigos, dentro de 
su pool de enemigos.
 * Al tener diferentes tipos de enemigos, sólo deben manipularlo y asignar más 
tipos para hacer
 * los cambios en lógica correspondiente en el pool */ 
public enum TypePool
{
    EnemyA,
    EnemyB
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PArte 2.
Script 1 (Hiding): Encargado de activar y desactivar el componente renderer de los Game Objects del proyecto, este debe tener una jerarquía específica;
PADRE (objeto contenedor del script "Hiding") → HIJO (primer orden en jerarquía) → NIETO (todos los objetos que se quieran desactivar).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Hiding : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject RendereContainer;
private Renderer[] Renderers;

private void Awake()
{
    
     /* Este código se encarga de desactivar el componente renderer de los objetos, pero conservando sus respectivos colliders
     * No confundir con una desactivación total del objeto, que incluye sus colliders y todos sus comportamientos.
     * Este código se ocupa en una jerarquía específica, del tipo, GetComponentsInChildren<T>()
     *   Abuelo (Este es un objeto vacío, donde se asigna este código en el inspector [Este órden es muy importante para su funcionalidad correcta])
     *     +Padre (Aquí pueden tener su primer control de orden de objetos, como tenía muchos objetos los metí aquí)
     *       -Hijos (Estos son los objetos, que: activan y desactivan su componente renderer, mediante este código)
     * De esta manera puenden controlar esta mecánica para muchos objetos con un sólo script en sólo un objeto. */
    Renderers = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
    Debug.Log(Renderers == null);


    /* Si sólo se requiere desactivar múltiples objetos en el escenario, se puede usar un truco simple que consiste, en:
    * Todos los objetos que se desactivarán, serán nietos de un objeto que tenga este (Hiding) componente y lo desactivas,
    * así los demas hijos se desactivaran igualmente, Ejemplo: 
    * // Le dices a éste que desactive a RenderContainer y el desactivará a sus hijos con RenderContainer.SetActive(false); y unity hará lo demás por ti.
    *       Hiding (GameObjet) 
    *         RenderContainer (GameObject)
    *                  Render1 (GameObject)
    *                  Render2 (GameObject)
    *                  Render3 (GameObject)
    *                  Render4 (GameObject) */
}

// Lógica que se encarga de activar y desactivar el render de los objetos, mediante un parámetro del tipo booleano.
public void EnableRenderContainer(bool OnOff)
{
    RendereContainer.SetActive(OnOff);
}

public void EnableChildComponents()
{
    SetView(true);
}

public void DisableChildComponents()
{
    SetView(false);
}

/* Este búcle recorre los objetos entendidos en la lógica del RenderContainer
 * (la jerarquía específica para objetos preinstanciados, decríta arriba ↑) */
public void SetView(bool view)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Renderers.Length; i++)
    {
        Renderers[i].enabled = view;
    }
}
}
```

Script 2 (EnemyPool): Encargado de administrar las instrucciones del Pool de enemigos, este pool, aunque es un diccionario, no crecer dinámicamente,
porque funciona con objetos preinstanciados dentro del proyecto, pero puedo funcionar con una lista de enemigos diferentes que aparecen dentro de un diámetro
establecido por una esféra y a una altura establecida (en mí proyecto están a 1 metro, porque vuelan).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyPool : MonoBehaviour
{
// Varibale que se comunica con el enum del script "Points"
public TypePool PoolType = 0;
// Variable para manipulación de posición de los enemigos preinstanciado y su comportamiento. 
public Transform enemyStart;
// Variable que crea la lista de enemigos en el inspector de unity
public List<GameObject> enemyList;

  

// Método encargado de activar los enemigos desactivados al recibir daños en el juego
public void ActivateEnemyA()
{
    Debug.Log("Activating Enemy");
    GameObject enemy = GetEnemy();
    PrepareEnemy(enemy);

}

/* El nombre es obvio pero por fines de aprendizaje lo que hace, es:
 * Activar los enemigos que no se encuentren activos en la lista
 * (los que han sido "asesinados en el juego) XD */
public void ActivateDisableEnemys()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < enemyList.Count; i++) //Recorre la lista de enemigos
    {
        // !enemyList[i].activeInHierarchy es lo mismo que enemyList[i].activeInHierarchy == false
        if (!enemyList[i].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            GameObject Enemy = enemyList[i];
            PrepareEnemy(Enemy);
            /* Variable interna para activar los enemigos en una posición aleatoria, dentro de un área establecida
             * en este caso, una esfera que abarca 10 metros*/
            var randomSpawnPoint = Random.insideUnitSphere * 10;
            /* Los enemigos se instancian con una altura establecida por la asignación después del "="
             * pueden controlar su altura al modificar el valor entero de asignación,
             * en este caso, es a 1 metro de altura (porque en mí juego vuelvan) */
            randomSpawnPoint.y = 1;
            Enemy.transform.position = randomSpawnPoint + enemyStart.position;

        }
    }
}



// Método usado para pedir nuevamente enemigos desactivados en el juego.
private GameObject GetEnemy()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < enemyList.Count; i++) //Recorre la lista de enemigos
    {
        if (enemyList[i].activeInHierarchy == false) //Si el enemigo contenido en "i", está inactiva
        {
            return enemyList[i];// Devuelve el enemigo de la posici�n "i"
        }
    }
    return null; //En caso de recorrer toda la lista sin encontrar enemigos, devuelve un null
}

/* El código parecido al usado en el desarrollo WEB sólo da una descripción de lo que hace el método
 * "PrepareEnemy" dentro del editor de código (visual studio en mí caso).
 * Si ponen el cursor de su mouse encima del nombre método, obtendrán una descripcipon
 * de lo que hace, en este caso, esa descripción son las líneas de código de abajo ↓ (no se asusten) */

/// <summary>
/// Activa un enemigo en el caso de no ser nulo y reestrablece su posicion al SpawnPoint
/// <br/>
/// <seealso cref="enemyStart"/>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="enemy"></param>

//Aquí acaba la descripción del método, dentro del editor de código ↑
private void PrepareEnemy(GameObject enemy)
{
    if (enemy != null && enemyStart != null)
    {
        enemy.transform.position = enemyStart.position;
        enemy.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
        Debug.LogError($"Enemy Null o SpawnPoint no asignado en {name}");
}


 }
```

Script 3 (LifeEnemy): Encargado de administrar los valores de la vida y sus interacciones mediante colliders en el proyecto.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LifeEnemy : MonoBehaviour
{
//Variable controladora de daño del objeto enemigoB al jugador
public float damage = 10;
//Vida del enemigo
public float healt = 1;


//Método para recibir daño de disparo y cuando la vida del enemigo es 0, se ejecuta el método que da muerte a los enemigos
public void TakeDamage(float amount)
{
    healt -= amount;
    if (healt <= 0f)
    {
        DieEnemy();
    }
}

public void DieEnemy()
{
    /*Lo usado normalmente para destruir objetos instanciados (no recomendado por problemas de rendimiento)
    Destroy(gameObject);*/
    //Metodología del pool para poder usar la función del score en "points"
    gameObject.SetActive(false); //Desactiva el objeto
}

// Lógica común para detectar el daño al entrar en contacto con una bala o raycast, dependerá de su implementación.
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        //Optimizar esto
        other.GetComponent<LifePlayer>().Subtract(damage);
    }
}

private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {

        other.GetComponent<LifePlayer>().Subtract(damage);
    }
}
}
```

Script 4 (EnemyUI): Encargado de la comunicación con el sistema del score al eleiminar enemigos.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyUI : MonoBehaviour
{
//Variable encargada de suministrar puntuación al HUD
public int points;
private static Points playerPoints = null;

private void Awake()
{
    if (!playerPoints)
    {
        playerPoints = FindObjectOfType<Points>();
    }
    
}

/*Método para asignación de puntaje mediante el método OnDestroy, es el ejemplo más habitual en la red
 * para un score, pero no hacer esto si quieren evitar que su juego vaya más lento que una diapositiva
public void OnDestroy()
{
    PointTimer playerPoints = FindObjectOfType<PointTimer>(); // Busca el objeto que contenga el componente PlayerPoints
    if (playerPoints != null) //Si encuentra al objeto en cuestión, entonces... no hacemos kabom el juego.
    {
        playerPoints.UpdateScore(points); //Actualiza los puntos que otorga o resta el enemigo
    }
}*/

/* Método para asignación de puntaje mediante el método OnDisable, con el pool ya implementado en el proyecto 
 * es necesario que la comunicación con la UI que muestra el puntaje en la pantalla, se comunique con este método
 * porque el pool no destruye objetos (los desativa), por eso dejé el método de arriba como ejemplo
 *  de lo que no se debe hacer, porque es mediante la destrucción de objetos y eso se traduce en pésimo rendimiento*/
public void OnDisable()
{

    if (playerPoints != null) //Si encuentra al objeto en cuestión, entonces...
    {
        playerPoints.UpdateScore(points); //Actualiza los puntos que otorga o resta el enemigo

    }
}
}
```